# How to create class with a lot of immutable fields?

Tags: scala, haskell

I would like to parse xml file which contains a list of payments or customers or accounts. The result will be the list of appropriate class.
Payment, customer or account has a lot of fields (50 - 100). A can divide them for several classes but the main class still will have many fields.
If I use java I will create appropriate class and using set method set all values but what is the functional way (using Scala) to create classes with a lot of immutable values?
How to create the same thing in Haskell?

Comment: Do you really need them as fields? Map is not an option?

Comment: Now, I think that Map is not an option but if there is not another solution then I will think about it. I think that using library it will be more easy to work with class.

Comment: What database are you using? Is it efficient to read all those fields at once?

Comment: I do not read data from database. It is the xml file from interface system.

Comment: try this http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=xml

Answer (score 2):

Scala 2.11 will [add support for case classes with more than 22 parameters](http://docs.scala-lang.org/scala/2.11/). As such you will be able to implement your 50-member immutable classes as per usual:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
```

Comment: I think it will look terrible. :)

Comment: For examples, I use XMLEventReader. Should I store all values in separate variables and after that set all parameters?

Answer (score 0):

I will answer for Haskell....

Here is an immutable Java class

```
class Person {
    final private int age;
    final private String name;

    public int getAge() { return this.age; }
    public string getName() { return this.name; }
    final private OtherStuff otherstuff;
    public Foo(String name, int age) { 
       this.name = name;
       this.age = age;
    }   
}
```

Here is the corresponding Haskell definition

```
data Person = Person{name::String, age::Int}
```

---

This is how we create a Person object

```
Person person = new Person("fred", 101);  // in Java
person = Person{name="fred", age=101} --In Haskell (prefix with "let" if in do notation)
```

---

Here is how we create an array of objects in Java-

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>
foreach(Raw rawPerson: rawData) {
    Person person = new Person(getName(rawPerson), getAge(rawPerson));
    ints.add(person)
}
```

Here it is in Haskell

```
raw2List = map (Person <$> getName <*> getAge)
```

(Haskell's version is lazy, so it won't actally do anything unless you use raw2List....  In fact I believe it will even start garbage collecting the XML parsetree before the whole Person list is finished being created....  Can someone verify this for me?).

---

The final piece of the puzzle- the XML library (ie- where does this 'Raw' data come from).

Both worlds have a few to choose from-

Commonly used Java XML libraries- DOM, Sax

Commonly used Haskell XML libraries- xml-conduit, HXT, HaXmL

Now, Scala people, can you translate this to Scala also?

---

Edit to address your comments-

There are really only three methods to populating typed structures from external quasi-types data....

1. Write a lot of boilerplate code like I did above....  This is admitedly ugly.
2. Store the data in a single multiply typed form, store it in a uniformly typed container like Map.  Loss of type information is always bad, but even more so to the Haskell community, which prides itself on its rich type specifications.
3. Use a framework to autogenerate and populate data structures (like Yesod/Persistent for databases).  I've never used it myself, but HaXmL has something similar to this, and it seems like it will autogenerate typed date from database schemas.

Comment: I don't see how this "answer" addresses anything asked in the question.

Comment: @sschaef- Granted, it doesn't address Scala (as I already stated), but it shows how to create an "class" in Haskell with lots of immutable values ("class" means something else in Haskell, but I went by its Java meaning).  This is what his question asked for....  Am I missing something?  Since he described how he would do this in Java, I went further and showed him how the Java he is familiar with would map to the Haskell way, and tell him what libraries he can use to populate the structure.  What do you think I am missing?

Comment: @jamshidh I wouldn't consider two fields "a lot" of them. The question mentions 50–100.

Comment: @kqr- Whould you rather I go back and put 48 more fields in the example? :)  Seriously though, he stated in the comments that he doesn't want to use Map, and he made it clear in the question that he does this in Java by creating a class with setters....  I am just giving him the Haskell way to do this.  How would you have answered this?

Comment: Your raw2List is `map (Person <$> getName <*> getAge)`.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs- upvote for coolness!  I am going to edit my answer to include this.  Of course *you* get that part of the fun with this answer is comparing the size of the Haskell and Java code :)

Comment: I understand your example but I could find it in any book. I would like to know does another solution exist?

Comment: The same question like for scala solution. Should I store all values in separate variables and after that set all parameters?

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using untyped parsers like:

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonTreeModel

That's what I would do in my Scala apps (there may be a slightly nicer parser lib). I would say that is more appropriate than giant Java/Scala tuple types.

There is no special shortcut for create massive Scala tuple types. Just add lots of vals.